# margin-top on body element with normalize.css

Tags: html, css, boilerplate

Used boilerplate including normalize.css and if using normalize.css i have always a gap over the body element. I couldn't find the reason in the normalize.css but if i'm not using it it works like i expected.

Here's an image to make it clearer. The white bar at the left is meant with the gap. 
Left: with normalize.css
Right: Just my little css

[image: Left: with normalize.css / Right: Just my CSS.]
Directlink to demo: http://sebastianwolf.org/

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
  k
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div#container {margin: 1em;background:silver}
body { background: red;}
```

Can you please tell where this comes from and how i can avoid this?
Couldn't find the code in normalize.css causing this.

UPDATE: Here is another image, showing the margin of the div, but the gap above is meant.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its because in normalize background is defined

```
html {
    background: #fff; /* 1 */
    color: #000; /* 2 */
    font-size: 100%; /* 3 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 4 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 4 */
}
```

Comment: This is not issue. There is a margin i have nowhere defined or can see. Added picture to make it clearer.

Comment: @sewo your div contain carriage return symbol with k